# Interface elements set to nil still present in app

Tags: objective-c, ios, interface, release, null

In my game, I allocate some UIImageViews programmatically with the following code:

```
blocks[1] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(200, y1, kBlockHeight, kBlockHeight)];
blocks[2] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(320, y2, kBlockHeight, kBlockHeight)];
blocks[3] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(440, y3, kBlockHeight, kBlockHeight)];
blocks[4] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(560, y4, kBlockHeight, kBlockHeight)];

blocks[1].backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
blocks[2].backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
blocks[3].backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
blocks[4].backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[self.view addSubview: blocks[1]];
[self.view addSubview: blocks[2]];
[self.view addSubview: blocks[3]];
[self.view addSubview: blocks[4]];
```

and it works fine, but when I try to get rid of the objects and restart,

```
for (int i = 1; i<= 4; i++) {
    blocks[i] = nil;
    //ARC won't let me call [blocks[i] release];
    NSLog(@"releasing blocks");
}
```

they still stay on the screen. They don't interact with anything, but still stay drawn on the screen. Why is this, and what should I do to get rid of the objects?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you might want to read about [IBOutletCollection](http://www.bobmccune.com/2011/01/31/using-ios-4s-iboutletcollection/)

Comment: I prefer not to use IBOutletCollection so that I can still support iOS 3.

Comment: You probably don't need to support iOS 3, it's not in widespread use any more and the latest developer tools don't even support targeting iOS versions that low.  If you are using ARC like your question indicates, your application won't run on iOS 3 anyway.

Comment: Have you done your homework on the figures? With iOS6 about to be released, I can see no reason to support iOS3. You will spend more time developing compatibility code than the profit it generates. And you are using ARC anyway...

Comment: @Jim you have never asked 1 question?!?

Comment: @PauldeLange, I've never really needed to.  Reasoning about the code, RTFM and STFW solve practically every problem I have quicker than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Jim Somehow it does successfully run on an iOS 3.1.3 device, even though it uses ARC (if I call release it gives an error: 'release' is not available in automatic reference counting mode)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your UIImageViews are still being retained by your viewController's view.  Try using:

```
for (int i = 1; i<= 4; i++) {
    [blocks[i] removeFromSuperview];
    blocks[i] = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this,

```
for (int i = 1; i<= 4; i++) {
    [blocks[i] removeFromSuperview];
    blocks[i] = nil; //removing from parent will not release so then you have to assign nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `addSubview:` documentation says:

> The view to be added. This view is retained by the receiver. After being added, this view appears on top of any other subviews.

Making the pointer nil will not release the view until it is removed from it's superview.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation of `addSubview`:

```
  This method retains view and sets its next responder to the receiver, which is its new superview.
```

I.e., the parent view has still a pointer. It does not matter, that you nil the original pointer.
If you want to get rid of a view, use

```
  [view removeFromSuperview];
  view = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing two different things - memory allocation and the composition of your view hierarchy.  You need to remove those views from the view hierarchy by sending them the `removeFromSuperview` message.  If no other part of your application owns them, the objects will then be deallocated, but don't confuse this deallocation with modification of the view hierarchy, it's something very different.